# Any way to disable known host checking with JSch?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to kick the tires of JSch and SSH connect to remote (Solaris) host from Java locally.  I normally use PuTTy, which gives me a prompt about an unknown host every time I connect somewhere for the first time, then I say yes and it no longer does it because it stores known hosts in the Win7 registry.  But JSch expects a known_hosts file and I am not sure how to make it.  I can investigate that later but, for now, I would prefer to skip that step.  Does anybody know if it is doable and how?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
```

From [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/jsch-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00529.html)